# Change field names in Python WTForms

Tags: python, wtforms

So I got this form which exists of a repeating row of fields, it's defined like this:

```
class SimpleDataRow(Form):
    title = StringField('Title')
    label = StringField('Name')


class SimpleDataForm(Form):
    fields = FieldList(FormField(SimpleDataRow))
```

After this I initialize the form, and append some entries into it with the corresponding data:

```
fields = DBSession.query(Field).filter_by(app=request.currentapp).all()

form = SimpleDataForm()
for field in fields:
    form.fields.append_entry(field)
```

Then I want to render the fields to the browser, but this is where I get some trouble because of the field naming in WTForms. When rendering the fields are assigned a name and id of `fields-0-title` & `fields-0-label`, and for each row of data the 0 is incremented by 1.

What I would rather have is that WTForm takes the ID of the field object, and uses this when it assigns names and id's to the fields. My field object looks like this:

```
class Field(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sys_fields'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    label = Column(String(64))
    title = Column(String(64))
```

So is there any way to change the pattern WTForms uses to name fields in FieldList's? Ideally I would want an naming pattern like this: `{prefix_}{label}_{id}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give a prefix when instantiating a form class. So in your case you would do something like:

```
form = SimpleDataForm(prefix=<your prefix string>)
```